# Getting response returns original page instead in LWP

Tags: perl, post, lwp

I'm trying to submit a form without filling in anything and getting the response page.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

$ua= LWP::UserAgent->new;
$req= POST('http://polling.newspoll.com.au/cgi-bin/polling/display_poll_data.pl?url_caller=&mode=trend&page=show_polls&question_set_id=4');

$res= $ua->request($req);
print $res->content;
```

But I just get the original page (with the form) printed not the response. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It was just a matter of finding the correct parameters to pass to the page. To figure this out I used Chrome Developer Tools on the results page, then go to network tab, then headers. SCroll down a bit and you will find all form parameters that were supplied to the page. Thanks to amon for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `POST` helper does not take a full URL including query parameters. You should provide those in an arrayref, like:

```
my $req = POST('http://www.example.com', [ foo => 42, bar => 'baz' ]);
```

… as shown in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon).

You should also note that POST parameters are not transported as query parameters inside the URL, but rather inside the body of the POST request. While some software like CGI provides an interface that abstracts away the difference, other software may not.

Please also note that all Perl scripts should `use strict; use warnings;`.

Another thing you should consider is proper error handling by testing `is_success` and using the `decoded_content` method, which takes care of transfer encodings.

```
$res->is_success
  or die $res->status_line;

print $res->decoded_content;
```

---

#### Edit

I analyzed the source, with the following results ([autogenerated](https://gist.github.com/latk/6595659)):

> I looked at the source of the page at `http://polling.newspoll.com.au/cgi-bin/polling/display_poll_data.pl`, and the form has following `<input>`s:
>
> - `<input name="url_caller" type="hidden" value="" />`
> - `<input name="mode" type="hidden" value="file" />`
> - `<input name="page" type="hidden" value="Search" />`
> - `<input name="keywords" type="text" />`
> - `<input name="show" type="text" />`
> - `<input src="/images/search_button.jpg" type="image" />`
>
> And the following `<select>` groups:
>
> - `<select name="from_date_month"></select>` with values `(1 .. 12)`
> - `<select name="from_date_year"></select>` with values `(1998 .. 2013)`
> - `<select name="to_date_month"></select>` with values `(1 .. 12)`
> - `<select name="to_date_year"></select>` with values `(1998 .. 2013)`
> - `<select name="keytype"></select>` with values `("all", "any")`
> - `<select name="state"></select>` with values `("Any", "FEDERAL", "ACT", "NSW", "NT", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "VIC", "WA")`
>
> Additionally, links with the following queries are present:
>
> - `?url_caller=latest&state=Any&mode=file&page=Search`
> - `?mode=trend&page=select_category`
>
> which means that the script also responds to GET requests
>
> I looked at the source of the page at `http://polling.newspoll.com.au/cgi-bin/polling/display_poll_data.pl?url_caller=&mode=trend&page=show_polls&question_set_id=4`, and the form has following `<input>`s:
>
> - `<input name="url_caller" type="hidden" value="trend" />`
> - `<input name="show" size="5" type="text" />`
> - `<input name="mode" type="hidden" value="trend" />`
> - `<input name="question_id" type="hidden" value="2403" />`
> - `<input name="page" type="submit" value="Display Results" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="to_date_year" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="to_date_month" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="from_date_month" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="to_date_day" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="from_date_year" />`
> - `<input name=".cgifields" type="hidden" value="from_date_day" />`
>
> And the following `<select>` groups:
>
> - `<select name="from_date_day"></select>` with values `(1 .. 31)`
> - `<select name="from_date_month"></select>` with values `(0 .. 12)`
> - `<select name="from_date_year"></select>` with values `("Any Year", 1970 .. 2013)`
> - `<select name="to_date_day"></select>` with values `(1 .. 31)`
> - `<select name="to_date_month"></select>` with values `(0 .. 12)`
> - `<select name="to_date_year"></select>` with values `("Any Year", 1970 .. 2013)`
>
> Additionally, links with the following queries are present:
>
> - `?url_caller=trend`
> - `?url_caller=trend&mode=trend&page=show_polls&question_set_id=4`
> - `?mode=trend&page=continue_results&question_id=2403&url_caller=trend`
>
> which means that the script also responds to GET requests

You are using the fields `[url_caller => '', mode => "trend", page => "show_polls", question_set_id => 4]` in your request. E.g. the field `question_set_id` does not exist. The value `show_polls` isn't present for `page`.

Hidden fields should not be changed, but re-submitted as they are prefilled. For the `select`ions, pick valid arguments from the provided lists. For text input, provide a sensible value depending on the context.

Comment: This solves part of the problem. But what do I do if I want to submit the form in $req and get the repsponse of that?

Comment: @MinaHany I don't understand what your exact problem is. When you implement error handling as shown in my updated post, do you get any errors? How do you know what parameters must be present to correctly call the CGI script?

Comment: So I used an arrayref just like you said and arrived at the page that contains the form. Now I want to submit again (click Display Results) to get the page I want. If you go to the page this will hopefully make sense.

Comment: @MinaHany I went to the page you linked to in your question, and added an example analysis of that page. You simply do not fill out the values in that form. To see what is filled into hidden fields, analyze the source. I linked to the script I used for that. You can also use the developer tools of a browser to inspect what requests are sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was just a matter of passing the right parameters.